# Prove that a language is regular

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata

I'm working on an example which says that a string x is obtained from a string w by deleting symbols if it is possible
to remove zero or more symbols from w so that just the string x remains. For example, the
following strings can all be obtained from 0110 by deleting symbols:

λ, 0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 010, 011, 110, and 0110.

Let Σ = {0, 1} and let A ⊆ Σ
∗ be an arbitrarily chosen regular language.

Define
B = {x ∈ Σ
∗
| there exists a string w ∈ A such that x is obtained from w by deleting symbols}.

In words, a string is in B if you can obtain that string by first choosing a string from A and
then deleting zero or more symbols from that chosen string. **Prove that B is regular**.

I'm not able to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: As $A$ is regular, it is recognized by finite automata. Try to modify this automata to make it recognize $B$.

Hint 2: Skipping "deleted" symbols might be handled by adding $\epsilon$ - transitions to the original automata in a proper way.

Answer (score 2):

Use closure properties of regular languages: Apply substitution $\sigma(x) = \{x, \epsilon\}$. This replaces symbols by themselves or nothing.

Comment: should I apply this substitution on Every state of my NFA of A language? I don't understand how will it then start accepting language B. Can you please elaborate on it. Sorry, I'm new to automata theory.

Comment: @ahmad123, the substitution is applied to the *language*, i.e. $\sigma(L) = \{\sigma(\alpha) \colon \alpha \in L \}$. It is a theorem that regular langusgrs are closed with respect to substitutions by regular languages for each symbol, and the languagrs here are finite, thus regular.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ has a regular expression. Can you modify the expression so it will express the optional deletion of arbitrary characters?